# Numpy and Matplotlib Error with very Minimal Example

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been using numpy and matplotlib together for some time now, successfully.  Suddenly, I am getting unusual errors when using them together.  The following is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = np.eye(10)
u = np.linalg.svd(x)
plt.show()
```

If I run the code once, it works.  If I run the code again, I get an exception:
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge.  Bizarrely, this behavior disappears when the call to pyplot is removed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = np.eye(10)
u = np.linalg.svd(x)
#plt.show()
```

I tried this with two different python environments with numpy versions 18.1 and 18.5.  I am wondering if anyone has any information about what could possibly cause this behavior.

edit: I was running these two blocks of code in a jupyter notebook with only those lines of code and nothing else.  In order to reproduce the behavior in the interactive interpreter, you need to add the line plt.show() in between runs.  I edited the post to include this line.

edit: matplotlib 3.3.2, numpy 18.1 or 18.5, and I can use python 3.8.1 or 3.6.8

Comment: I just ran the version with the call to `plt.subplots()` twice in a row from a shell instance and I did not get an error.  Also using Numpy 18.1.  Are you running this in a notebook?  Do you get the same thing in a shell/terminal instance?

Comment: Thank you for boiling down the Repeat-By: to just a few lines!

I am using these revs:

matplotlib-base           3.3.2            py38had0acaf_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.1           py38h8ccc501_2    conda-forge
I am unable to reproduce the symptom you report. I ran it under an interactive python 3.8.5 interpreter.

Comment: @andrew_reece I am running this in a jupyter notebook.  I can try running it outside of jupyter and update my post momentarily.

Comment: @andrew_reece I figured out how to reproduce it in the interpreter.  You need to type plt.show() to look at the figure, then run the last two lines of code to attempt to do the SVD.  Jupyter shows you the figure automatically, so I didn't include plt.show() in my example.

Comment: i just ran your code in jupyter notebook, it runs without error there, too. i tried running the same block of code repeatedly, as well as repeating the same code in consecutive blocks.  both work without error. i'm using python 3.7.6, matplot 3.1.3, and numpy 1.18.1, so my guess is that it's either a python or matplotlib version issue.